# method of populate dropdownlist inside gridview

Tags: asp.net

If i want to populate a `DropdownList` in a `GridView` what will be the best way? use `GridView` `'OnRowDataBound`' event and fetch query everytime to db or get all data first and put it on datatable and do further work from this datatable ?

Comment: what is your question ?.where are you stucked. ?

Answer (score 0):

As your question is unclear about your requirement, I assume that you want to bind `dropdownlist` inside the `Gridview` using `OnRowDataBound` event of gridview.

So here are the steps:-

1. Add a Gridview HTML in your aspx page with `DropDownList` in `ItemTemplate` of `TemplateField`.

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="ContactName" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Country">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Country") %>' Visible = "false" />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountries" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then you need to bind the `gridview` with records which will come from the database.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData("SELECT ContactName, Country FROM Customers");
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
private DataSet GetData(string query)
{
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                sda.Fill(ds);
                return ds;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then the code for `OnRowDataBound` will follow like below :-

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Find the DropDownList in the Row
        DropDownList ddlCountries = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlCountries") as DropDownList);
        ddlCountries.DataSource = GetData("SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM Customers");
        ddlCountries.DataTextField = "Country";
        ddlCountries.DataValueField = "Country";
        ddlCountries.DataBind();

        //Add Default Item in the DropDownList
        ddlCountries.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select"));

        //Select the Country of Customer in DropDownList
        string country = (e.Row.FindControl("lblCountry") as Label).Text;
        ddlCountries.Items.FindByValue(country).Selected = true;
    }
}
```

See the [Reference link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-populate-DropDownList-in-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx) for your reference

Also see the [Working demo](http://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/297/) for your reference

Hope that helps.